# a nested object is undefined in the controller while whole object can be read

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

the problem is that the data can't be used in the controller because it is always undefined , I think this is because the return is a promise not resoloved before running the controller, please help.. here is my code.

```
.factory('channelsFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL ) {


        return $resource(baseURL+"channels/:id",null,{'update':{method:'PUT' }});

    }])
```

this is the controller in my controllers.js

```
.controller('videoController',[ '$scope','$http', 'baseURL','channelsFactory','channel',function($scope, $http, baseURL,channelsFactory, channel){


  $scope.baseURL= baseURL;
  $scope.channel= channel;
  console.log(channel)// I can see the promised data just fine

$scope.videos = [];
$scope.youtubeParams = {
  key: 'AIzaSyAc6Su5lq1-OIXHu3VMfssPM5RzY8F2tPk',
  type: 'video',
  maxResults: '20',
  part: 'id,snippet',
  q:'',
  order: 'date',
  channelId:channel.channelid,//undfined
    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {params:$scope.youtubeParams}).success(function(response){


angular.forEach(response.items, function(child){
   $scope.videos.push(child);
      console.log(child);
  });
});
```

and here is the view in the app.js

```
 .state('app.channelvideos', {
url: '/channelsList/:id',
views: {
  'mainContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/channelvideos.html',
    controller: 'videoController',
      resolve: {

          channel: ['channelsFactory','$stateParams', function(channelsFactory,$stateParams ){

                     return channelsFactory.get({id:parseInt($stateParams.id,10)})


                 }]
      }
  }
}


})
```

Comment: Did you investigate the network request and response? Resolving pending promises should be fine.

Comment: yes I can read the response in the console but when trying to read a nested object like console.log(channel.id) it returns undefined also

Answer (score 0):

where do you use the `$scope.youtubeParams`?,if this is used in the trigger   event,you can put this code into the function of trigger event.Try to show the $scope.channel in your html like `{{channel}}` to see if you have get the correct object

Answer (score 0):

thanks good finally I found an article talking about my problem specifically and the solution was to force angular to resolve the resource in the ui-router , and the solution was just in one word, so this piece of code will be edited as following

```
return channelsFactory.get({id:parseInt($stateParams.id,10)}).$promise;
```